# Why should Tmux mistake Escape+J for <M-j>? Another scancode legacy?

Tags: vim, tmux

I find it amusing that the following setting will interfere with using Vim in
Tmux, when there should be more than one "pane" that exist for the tmux session:

> Pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> sequentially (within 1-2 seconds)
>   will be interpreted as `prefix + M-j` ==> jump to the next pane :)

Settings to replicate:

```sh
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
# Use Alt-vim keys without prefix key to switch panes
bind -n M-j select-pane -D 

# Other pieces 
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-l select-pane -R
```

It took me a good number of weeks, if not months, to suffer from such an amusing fact: I will lose sight of the active cursor when I simply want to move 3-lines-below, as it may jump to the next pane, or the next-next one.

Per this post, I would like to document this absurdly amusing side-effect of mapping `M-h` keys in Tmux. And, expect a clarifying answer on the "why".

Comment: Just open Vim and go into insert mode. Then hit `<Ctrl-V>` followed by `Meta-j` and you will see the keycode inserted in the file. It is `^[j` (aka `<esc>j`). BTW: To "simulate" `<F10>`, you can just hit `<esc>` followed by `0`.

Comment: What side effect? That's exactly what `bind -n` does, binds commands to keys without requiring the prefix key to be pressed first. Since Meta itself isn't a key on modern keyboards, your terminal emulator determines which key acts as the Meta key, and in this case it sounds like that's Escape, not Alt.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying! Things are more complicated than I thought. It is good to have the relevant moving pieces documented in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem, you can change the timeout on how long tmux is willing to wait between receiving an escape sequence (either Meta or literal Esc) and the next character to determine if you're typing a tmux command or not.

```
set -sg escape-time 0
```

With this, you'll have to be holding down Meta when J is pressed to activate the tmux command of jumping to the next pane. You'll still have infinite time between pressing the prefix sequence and the command, however (i.e., you can press `<prefix>`, wait several seconds, and then press d to detach as normal).

This will obviously interfere with any binds you may have that cannot be pressed simultaneously.

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Tmux, I am happy to give up the Meta+J mapping and restore the full functionality of the `Escape` key. ==> For an extended number of weeks/month, I don't feel like using Tmux as I need to wait for 1-second or so to have the `Escape` key properly _registered_. I was literally staring at the "mode-indicator" until it exists from "Insert-mode". I should be settled with key-mappings in Tmux for now :)

Comment: The current default for 'escape-time' is 500ms. I drop it to 10ms exactly for this reason. (0 didnt work for me because I access servers remotely) I also ensure there are no VIM mapping which work in insert mode and start with an ESC. This actually causes more problems. I use `set ttimeout=10` in my vimrc to limt how long vim waits to be sure escape is the escape key and not the beginning of a key sequence.